# Problem with Outlook add in

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am trying to build a simple Outlook 2007 Add-in using Visual Studio 2010 and .NET framework 4. I am just displaying a MessageBox from the ThisAddIn.StartUp() method. The following is the code:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Addin started");
        }
```

When I try to run the project, Outlook is started but the ThisAddIn.StartUp method is not being called. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the add-in is active in "Trust Center" > "Add-ins".